# Django getting the number of fields of a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

how can I get the number of a model fields in django?

Comment: trying to map a csv input to the django models, so i need to check if they have the same number of fields.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was kidding... you tested len(User) and len(user)... but why would have to work it?

Comment: sorry i'm a little new to python. for sure a class and a class instance do not have length! sorry for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look at the model's `_meta` attribute:

```
In [1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

In [2]: len(User._meta.fields)
Out[2]: 11

In [3]: len(User._meta.many_to_many)
Out[3]: 4
```

Comment: is there foreign key fields in the fields attribute?

Comment: Yes. Only `ManyToManyFields` are seperated in the `many_to_many` attribute!